# Why is make_shared calling the destructor twice and copy constructor at all?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I'm rewriting parts of one of my old projects. I've written a `Texture` class which loads a file from disk, and stores the data as an array of `unsigned char` (using an external lib, so using a `vector<unsigned char>` isn't an option).

In `main()` I load my textures and pass them onto a `Scene` object. Since textures can be large and the same texture can be shared between multiple objects I'm creating a bunch of `std::shared_ptr<Texture>`s before passing them to `Scene`.

The problem originally was that the destructor of Texture would be called twice and cause malloc to complain about the pointer being freed not being allocated (external lib is using malloc, so again, it's out of my hands). After some investigation with printing out to console, it seems that the textures are being copied via the copy constructor and then destroyed immediately afterwards. I thought the point of `shared_ptr` was to not copy objects but to increment the reference count.

Here's a minimal `main()` where I create one `shared_ptr<Texture>`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<Texture> up(std::make_shared<Texture>("textures/lakeup.png"));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class `Texture`:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(const std::string&)
    {
        std::cout << "Texture::Texture() for " << this << std::endl;
    }

    Texture(const Texture& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Texture::Texture(const Texture&) for " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~Texture()
    {
        std::cout << "Texture::~Texture() for " << this << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And finally, here is the console output for this code (updated to only load one Texture):

```
Texture::Texture() for 0x7fff5fbff808
Texture::Texture(const Texture&) for 0x7fff5fbff820
Texture::Texture(const Texture&) for 0x608000043228
Texture::~Texture() for 0x7fff5fbff820
Texture::~Texture() for 0x7fff5fbff808
Texture::~Texture() for 0x608000043228
```

I am confused about why the copy constructors are called at all immediately after `make_shared` and why not `shared_ptr`s copy constructor, which should just increment a reference count. Thanks in advance.

**Updated with a minimal version.** It's interesting to note that `std::make_shared<Texture>()` doesn't seem to work with 0 arguments, which is why I've left the `std::string` in for now. I get a compilation error `make_shared_object.hpp` on line 711 in function `make_shared( A1 const & a1 )`.

Another thing I've noticed is that replacing `make_shared<Texture>("")` with `new Texture("")` behaves as expected:

```
Texture::Texture() for 0x60800022fd20
Texture::~Texture() for 0x60800022f640
```

It works but it's not very satisfactory if I leave without understanding what `make_shared` is actually doing.

I'm using XCode 5.1.1 which seems to correspond to llvm/clang 5.1.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?  It certainly looks like it's making your structure, then copying it twice, then destroying two copies, leaving the one in the `shared_ptr`.  And what happens if you use `Texture(const Texture&) = delete`, so that copys aren't legal

Comment: Show us your [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on GCC http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12febe3dc676f798, clang http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6173040f1b27efd1, or MSVC++ http://rextester.com/YGPO40991

Comment: Yep. I made a simple class to test this with and on GCC I only get "constructed". Never a copy.

Comment: @usm  You need to tell us the compiler and version, plus what optimizations you used to build the program.  Copy construction can be removed by the compiler for optimized builds.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Texture>("textures/lakeft.png")` does not appear to match any of the constructors you have posted. I guess there are default arguments in the constructor definition or something, please post more code to clarify

Comment: What's the type of `envFront_` and others?

Comment: @Dave I got a compilation error in `make_shared`. @Mat Those were simply `shared_ptr<Texture>`s so I expect only an increment of reference count.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57178cd79197d2dd) with `clang++`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607eaa79fbb8c275) with `g++` either.

Comment: Even more strangely, I've switched to using `boost::shared_ptr<Texture>` and `boost::make_shared<Texture>` instead of the `std::` versions and the problem has gone away. (boost 1.54.0).

Comment: Which standard library are you using - libc++ or libstdc++?

Comment: @ecatmur I'm using libc++ which is the setting "compiler default (llvm)" in xcode.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ, to make that clang test useful you need to use `-stdlib=libc++` otherwise you're just testing the same `shared_ptr` code as GCC uses.